# How to render one element at a time of a list, in a periodic manner, using react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of strings, say ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']. 
I want to display elements of this list, one element at a time. For instance, 'a' should be displayed first then after 1000ms 'b' should be displayed and so on. 
I need the solution in React js

Comment: You just want to display the string, one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [actualArray, setActualArray] = useState(["a", "b", "c", "d"]);
  const [displayElement, setDisplayElement] = useState("");
  let index = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setDisplayElement(actualArray[index]);
      index += 1;
      if (index >= actualArray.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>{displayElement}</div>;
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: The demo link leads to an unrelated project

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    actualArray: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    displayArray: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let index = 0;
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        displayArray: [...this.state.displayArray, this.state.actualArray[index]]
      });
      index++;
      if (index >= this.state.actualArray.length) {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.displayArray);
    let elements;
    elements = this.state.displayArray.map((value, index) => {
      return <div key={index}>{value}</div>;
    });

    return <div>{elements}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with setTimeout or setInterval.

[image: Edit wispy-bash-ioonk]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    letters: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    currentIndex: 0
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      let index = this.state.currentIndex;
      index++;
      if (index >= this.state.letters.length) {
        index = 0;
      }
      this.setState({ currentIndex: index });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.letters[this.state.currentIndex]}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```