# Render array elements with some in React js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have an array in React JS containing string data, I want to loop through that array and render each element of the array with some delay.
I have tried setTimeout, setInterval but none of these work for me.

Instead, what I did I shifted that array into another array and put it in setTimeout so it might take some time but it didn't work for me

Here is the code

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const [shiftArr, setShiftArr] = useState([]);
const fruitsArray = [
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Mango",
    "Grapes",
    "Peach",
    "Avocado",
    "watermelon",
    "Pineapple",
    "Orange",
    "Strawbries",
  ];

useEffect(() => {
      
    for (let i = 0; i < fruitsArray.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShiftArr((shiftArr) => [...shiftArr, fruitsArray[i]]);
        setIndex(i + 1);
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, []);
```

Rendering shifted array

```
<div className="fruitList">
          {shiftArr.map((fruit, ind) => (
            <div style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }} key={ind}>
              {fruit}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render one element at a time of a list, in a periodic manner, using react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392604/how-to-render-one-element-at-a-time-of-a-list-in-a-periodic-manner-using-react)

Comment: yes does any of the solution work?

Answer (score 2):

When you set the state, the Component is rerendered, and `useEffect` is called again if the dependencies change.

Use `shiftArr` as the dependency of `useEffect`, and if it's length is not identical to the original array, set the timeout, and create the `shiftArray` from the original array by slicing it to include the next item:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Demo = ({ array }) => {
  const [shiftArr, setShiftArr] = useState([]);
  
  // initialize the shiftArr when array changes
  useEffect(() => setShiftArr(array.slice(0, 1)), [array]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(shiftArr.length === array.length) return;
    
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => 
      setShiftArr(array.slice(0, shiftArr.length + 1))
    , 2000);
    
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [shiftArr]);

  return (
    <div className="fruitList">
      {shiftArr.map((fruit, ind) => (
        <div style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }} key={ind}>
          {fruit}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const fruits = ["Apple","Banana","Mango","Grapes","Peach","Avocado","watermelon","Pineapple","Orange","Strawbries"];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo array={fruits} />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```